# Horizontal line on the console?

Tags: command-line, terminal, console, line

I want to print a horizontal line to the console. At the moment, I use `-----`, but there are small spaces between the single characters.

Is there a better character I might use?

`_` is not a viable option, as it is not vertically centered. Is there something like a *middlescore*, *strikethrough* (or whatever it's name is) character?

Comment: Does this work ―――――? In terminal on mac no space is shown between.

Answer (score 15):

```
Hyphen         ---------------------
Underscore     _____________________
EM Dash        —————————————————————
Horizontal Bar ―――――――――――――――――――――
Horizontal Box ─────────────────────
```

There is a big list of characters to try [over at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Similar_Unicode_characters).

The [horizontal box drawing character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) is my recommendation. It is designed for this purpose

Comment: `_` is not vertically centered as `-` is.

Comment: It almost is if you put a blank line after it :P

Comment: That's right :-). Unfortunately, then I use two lines instead of one, which does not look nice.

Comment: @GoloRoden Edited to conform to the new requirements. This was as easy as hunting through character map :P

Comment: Well, in the browser this looks great, but not on the console (on OS X). There is still 1px space left :-/.

Answer (score 12):

With `bash`, to display a horizontal rule the size of your window you can use:

```sh
printf %"$COLUMNS"s | tr " " "-"
```

With `zsh`, you could avoid the `tr`:

```sh
printf '—%.0s' {1..$COLUMNS}
```

---

<sub>**NOTE:** I know this is not what OP wants, but it is what I think someone from Google could be seeking.</sub>

Comment: Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions. This will work instead: `printf %"$COLUMNS"s |tr " " "-"`.

Comment: @AndreasBaumgart thanks for the snippet, I updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Unicode character `\u2500` solved it for me. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Similar_Unicode_characters) it is for `box drawings light horizontal`, which is exactly what I need :-)

Thanks [@Gusdor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286976/gusdor) for pointing me to the correct Wikipedia article!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that extended ASCII character #196 can serve your purpose:
See http://www.asciitable.com/

It seems like a vertically-centered non-gap line.

Answer (score 0):

`&#x2015;`/`&#8213;` is a [horizontal bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Horizontal_bar) character ―

Works for me in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, open RUN, type `charmap` and hit enter.
There are a plenty of characters listed there with previews and names. I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for in charmap.

**Update**
If you're using a Linux Distribution, check [this](https://superuser.com/a/450076/896401) out.

Answer (score 0):

if working on node js

```
const line = '#'.repeat(process.stdout.columns || 100);
console.log('\n',line,'\n');
```

function and in Typescript

```
function consoleLine(mainChar:string, fallbackNum:number):string {
  const line = (toRepeat:string) => toRepeat?.repeat(process.stdout?.columns || fallbackNum)
  const mainLine = line(mainChar);
  const emptyLine = line(' ');

  return `${mainLine}\n${emptyLine}\n${mainLine}`;
};

console.log(consoleLine('#', 100));
```