# Horizontal Line Spanning Terminal Width

Tags: java, terminal, println

What I am trying to achieve here is something that looks like this:

```bash
|=========================================|
|Terminal                          - [] X |
|=========================================|
|                                         |
| "Some Text Printed."                    |
| --------------------------------------- |
| "A Line Was Printed Above!"             |
|                                         |
|=========================================|
```

---

The horizontal line can be easily printed if you know the exact character size the width of the terminal can accomodate.

`Java` does have a `Console` class (the nearest word to "Terminal")...

...BUT the class just **doesn't** have that functionality.

We could try just guessing it with something like this:

```java
final StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
  builder.append("-");
}
```

BUT the issue there is... not all terminal dimensions are the same.

---

Another option would be to ask the user about the terminal width...

```java
// Bruh, why not use an optimized reader.
final Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Terminal Width: ");
final int width=scan.nextLine();
```

...BUT it's not optimal since:

1. The user might just guess it anyway.
2. I need it automated.

---

And of course, I would never ask here without researching.

I did read these threads (and some more):

1. [horizontal-line-on-the-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239979/horizontal-line-on-the-console)
2. [how-to-print-a-horizontal-line-the-size-of-the-terminal-with-a-word-in-the-middle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313851/how-to-print-a-horizontal-line-the-size-of-the-terminal-with-a-word-in-the-middl)
3. [how-can-i-print-a-variable-with-padded-center-alignment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267729/how-can-i-print-a-variable-with-padded-center-alignment)

BUT... it relies on the capability of actually knowing the terminal dimension and they soley rely on `bash`.

---

I'm trying to do this with "Pure Java", "Pure" meaning that I'd do it with no dependencies or whatever.

Except if I could just straight-up copy the code needed and nobody would get mad.

Comment: As a console can be dynamically resized, this aint really feasible. You can have a console that fits 5 dashes expand to one that holds 100, and back to 5.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yup, that is a problem, but what's important there is that the line occupies the **current** width of the terminal.

Comment: Then your best bet would probably, be to somehow get the width of the command prompt, know the width of 1 dash and then calculate how many dashes you need

Comment: A 'console' is basically its own application, where the window/text-area width is an 'internal proprty' meaning it needs to be exposed by the application itself. Since there are a lot of implementations (bash, dash, cmd, powershell etc.) there is no universal way to get this number which is why it is propably not included into 'vanilla java'. I think you would save yourself a lot of time and frustration if you would search for a good module for this, so you don't have to mess with platform-specific code and mechanisms.

Comment: If you are really searching for some universal control, you can try 'control characters' and see if that can cover your needs. It is supported by a decent amount of console-applications. But a I am not sure it covers your spefic requirements.